# How to install dependencies along with .deb package offline

Tags: apt, software-installation, dependencies, deb, debian

**What I have:**

I have a Qt deb package for Ubuntu Desktop 16/18. By default, Qt dynamically compiles application. Hence the target machine must have the required libraries installed.

**What I want:**

Now I want to install this deb package to offline machine which does not have the libraries installed. This should work in single command, i.e., `sudo apt-get install package.deb`

**What I haved tried:**

Created a tar of dependencies and placed in deb package. In postinst script, I am unpacking the tar and trying to install but due to  `/var/lib/dpkg/lock` , this method failed.

All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: What's wrong with `sudo apt-get install package1.deb dep1.deb deb2.deb ...` as a single command?

Comment: Issue is , one single installer should be deployed and one single command `apt-get install package.deb` should be run.

Comment: You've provided no OS & release details, but `apt` can work with local packages (`apt-get` requires more setup to do that).

Comment: Ubuntu 16 & Ubuntu 18 are target OS. Please elaborate how  `apt` can be helpful

Comment: Then you'll have to unpack all of those dependencies and include their contents in your package, then mark your package as providing all those packages. Or make a snap or flatpak or appimage containing everything.

Comment: @muru how to include dependencies' contents in my package ?

Comment: Ubuntu Core 16 & Ubuntu Core 18 don't use *deb* packages; all *yy* format releases of Ubuntu are *snap* only, with *deb* based Ubuntu releases being *yy.mm* formatted.

Comment: Yes, right. And Qt deb package is meant for Ubuntu Desktop OS.